# How to send message from many topics to many topics using spring boot or spring Kafka integration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am looking for multiple source to multiple destination topics message transfer.
[image]

I can do iterate, list of destination topics and send one by one.
But is there any simple, other than that approach.

Thank you!

Comment: I wonder why you want to do something like this?

Comment: @ray We have a requirement, as we have to do some enrichment. Before sending it to multiple topics

Comment: You can create multiple consumers and producers in a single application

Answer (score 1):

Sounds more like Kafka Streams scenario: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/index.html.

See their `StreamsBuilder.stream(final Collection<String> topics)` and `KStream.branch(final Predicate<? super K, ? super V>... predicates)`.

Here is a good example how to produce into several topics: https://github.com/nodefluent/kafka-streams/issues/85.

See also convenient `KafkaStreamBrancher` API in `spring-kafka`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#using-kafkastreambrancher